# Identify app instance Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to store information in a central DB to track how many clients that have various versions of the app. I cannot locate any unique identification in WinRT that identifies the app instance. Does anyone know how I can track this?

Comment: Do you mean the Application ID of a WinRT app? In this case, you can read the CoreApplication.Id property, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.id.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are asking for, you could use is the [Application Specific Hardware ID (ASHWID)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.getpackagespecifictoken).  For example:

```
        Windows.System.Profile.HardwareToken hid = Windows.System.Profile.HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken(null);

        var version = Package.Current.Id.Version;
        Debug.WriteLine(hid.Id + " - " + version.ToString());
```

From the documentation:

> Gets a hardware identifier (ASHWID) that represents the current
>   hardware. The returned ASHWID will be different for each application
>   package. In other words, this API will return different identifiers
>   when called by two apps from different packages. It will return the
>   same identifier when called by two apps that are part of the same
>   package.

Comment: keep in mind though the [ASHWID could change](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431) for a given device if there's a change in the hardware config. It sort of comes down to what defines the device and when does one device become a different one following hardware changes/modifications (more memory? new disk?).  The 'good' news is you can make that decision but there's logic involved - perhaps for instance it's only the CPU part of the ASHWID you care about to uniquely define a device.